# vRO indexOf not returning expected result

Tags: javascript, vmware

I have been having trouble with this for longer than I should have, so I thought I would reach out to the good folks on here who know what they are doing. I have a field on a request form that looks the input of another field and then should return a list of domains depending on the other option. However no matter option is entered the form, action (and workflow where I test the script) returns the first option UK1, UK2. The resPolicyId input looks like this:

MAN-XXX-UK or LIS-XXX-EU - where the XXX is a 3 digit team code... eg MAN-WEB-UK and so on.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
if (resPolicyId == null || resPolicyId == "" ) {
return null;
}


if (resPolicyId.indexOf("UK" != -1)) {
return arrDomains = ["UK1","UK2"]
}
else if (resPolicyId.indexOf("EU" != -1)) {
return arrDomains = ["EU1","EU2"]
}
else {return arrDomains = ["No Match Found"]}
```

I have also tried other options such as:

```
if (resPolicyId == null || resPolicyId == "" ) {
    return null;
    }

if  (resPolicyId.indexOf("UK", 8)) {
    return arrDomains = ["UK1","UK2"]
    }
    else if (resPolicyId.indexOf("EU", 8)) {
    return arrDomains = ["EU1","EU2"]
    }
    else {return arrDomains = ["No Match Found"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your condition outside `indexOf`

```js
resPolicyId ="LIS-WEB-EU "

function input(resPolicyId){
if (resPolicyId == null || resPolicyId == "" ) {
return null;
}

if (resPolicyId.indexOf("UK") != -1) {
return arrDomains = ["UK1","UK2"]
}
else if (resPolicyId.indexOf("EU" ) != -1) {
return arrDomains = ["EU1","EU2"]
}
else {return arrDomains = ["No Match Found"]}
}
console.log(input(resPolicyId))
```

Comment: Thanks so much works a treat. I knew I was doing something stupid!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
// clic run
var resPolicyId = null;
console.log(example(resPolicyId)); // --> null
resPolicyId = "";
console.log(example(resPolicyId)); // --> null
resPolicyId = "senseless";
console.log(example(resPolicyId)); // --> null
resPolicyId = "ABC-DEF-UK-toomuch";
console.log(example(resPolicyId)); // --> null
resPolicyId = "ABC-DEF-UK";
console.log(example(resPolicyId)); // --> ["UK1", "UK2"]
resPolicyId = "LIS-XXX-EU";
console.log(example(resPolicyId)); // --> ["EU1", "EU2"]
resPolicyId = "NYC-XXX-US";
console.log(example(resPolicyId)); // --> []


function example(resPolicyId){
  var result = null;
  if (resPolicyId && resPolicyId.length > 0 && resPolicyId.split("-").length == 3){
    resPolicyId = resPolicyId.split("-")[2];
    switch (resPolicyId){
      case "UK": result = ["UK1", "UK2"];
        break;
      case "EU": result = ["EU1", "EU2"];
        break;
      //add more sites here.... don't forget the "break"
      default: result = [];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```